# Scientific Linux won't boot after yum updates kernel

Tags: linux, yum, boot, kernel

I just updated kernel for my Linux:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:40 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost ~]#
```

last few entries from /var/log/messages:

```
Oct  1 10:22:10 wcmisdlin02 wall[21689]: wall: user root broadcasted 1 lines (8 chars)
Oct  1 10:22:40 wcmisdlin02 NetworkManager[1866]: <info> kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware' changed
Oct  1 10:22:43 wcmisdlin02 yum[21626]: Updated: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.noarch
Oct  1 10:22:53 wcmisdlin02 yum[21626]: Installed: kernel-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
Oct  1 10:23:05 wcmisdlin02 yum[21626]: Installed: kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
Oct  1 10:23:07 wcmisdlin02 yum[21626]: Updated: kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
```

/var/log/yum.log

```
[root@localhost ~]# tail /var/log/yum.log | grep "^Oct 01"
Oct 01 10:22:43 Updated: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.noarch
Oct 01 10:22:53 Installed: kernel-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
Oct 01 10:23:05 Installed: kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
Oct 01 10:23:07 Updated: kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]#
```

and now it won't boot(, right after I'm seeing GRUB where I can select different version of kernel (I've tried newly installed one *AND* previous kernel) w/ same results:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on known-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
 [<ffff
....
```

I also noticed all "initramfs" files are looks like have been updated (that's probably why I can't boot into old kernel anymore too)

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -al /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-279.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 15227261 Oct  1 10:25 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 15227720 Oct  1 10:25 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.x86_64.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 15227774 Oct  1 10:26 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64.img
[root@localhost ~]#
```

any ideas?

Comment: Just in case, http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=262786 talks about usb stick.

Comment: guy was able to boot old kernel and i'm not( so not helpful

Comment: Please read before saying "not helpful" : 1st guy was able to boot old kernel. I was talking about post number 5.

Comment: yes, I read entire thread and no I don't have any USB sticks in my computer that's why it wasn't helpful. (it's not like I downvote you or anything) I appreciate your help/input its just wasn't helpful for my issue.

Comment: btw, I also mentioned in my original post that I did tried both of kernels (including newly installed _AND_ previous) w/out any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on known-block(0,0)](http://wp.me/p1YZZu-dg)